# kafka produce to topic and write to state store in a single transaction

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

Is it possible to produce to a Kafka topic and write to state store in a single transaction? But not start the transaction as part of a topic consumption.

EDIT: The reason I what to do this is to be able to filter out duplicate requests. E.g. a service exposes a REST interface and just writes a message to a topic. If it is possible to produce to topic and write to state store in a single transaction, then I can easily first query the state store to filter out a duplicate. This also assumes that the transaction timeout, will be less than the REST timeout, but not that related to the question.

I am also aware of the solution provided [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/56e3aad17baf76bc1f110f21fa25ecffd7eeeaa5/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/microservices/OrdersService.java#L202) by Confluent. But this will work as long as the synchronisation time "from the topic to the store" is less than the blocking time.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Write to state store is writing to some changelog topic. I suggest to read: https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

Comment: @wardziniak thanks for the reply! Have you seen any example online? Actually  doing this is quite important, so that we can use the state store to filter out duplicate requests.

Comment: Can you filter out it later or you have to make during rest call? If during rest call, why it is needed there?

Comment: @wardziniak It is not strictly needed there, but it is the most convenient place to have it done though. As the service writes to the "source of truth events" topic (e.g. invoiceDrafted, invoiceCreated etc..). Even with an intermediate topic de-duplication will be possible surely, but not that simple. I have also considered CDC, but the REST interface is quite complex and writing the request to the DB first (and use DB for de-duplication) is also possible but complicated.

Answer (score 1):

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/StateStore.html

State store is part of Streams API. So, State store is linked with Kafka-streams. I would recommend using headers within a message to maintain state information.

Or

Create another topic to store intermediate information.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you use case properly, you can do like that:

- Write REST call result to some topic - `raw-data`(using the producer)
- Use Kafka Streams to process data from `raw-data` topic. Using Kafka Streams you can implement whole logic of checking/filtering duplicates, etc and writing result into golden topic.